# DecimalFormat formatting values correctly when viewing Log, but values aren't formatted after saving to database?

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I'm trying to format a float value to have only four decimal places using DecimalFormat as follows:
[image]
[image]

When I'm looking at the output as a Log entry in Android Studio, it's formatted fine (the column circled in red, with values such as 9.3525, 21.0145, etc.):
[image]

I store those values into an SQLite database that I can later email to myself. However, when I open up the database, the values that were formatted properly in the Log entries are no longer formatted:
[image]

What's going on here, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: What type is the column you are storing the values in?

Comment: @Estevex The type of the column is 'REAL' (which I've been using for doubles, and I presumed works for floats as well).

Comment: the raw_load is the value you are logging and saving in the db?

Comment: @Estevex The raw_load value is returned from a function, so I call that function, save its output (raw_load) into another float, and save that into the db

Comment: have you tried to save the output of the function directly into the db?

Comment: I have not, but I can't due to some timing concerns I have in my code. However I do the same thing for the column to the left of the column circled in red (apply the same DecimalFormat and call the function and save its result into another variable). That works fine, and the only major difference variable-wise is that it's a double, rather than a float. I'm not sure if that might be the issue.

Comment: Fixed it! Turns out the issue was the fact that the variable was a float. I converted everything to a double and afterwards the database had the correctly formatted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I was using a float as the variable. I converted everything to a double, and afterwards the DecimalFormat was being formatted correctly in the database as well as in the Android Studio logs.